# How to transition both states with toggleclass?

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a simple toggle class in js that triggers a transition but I can't figure out how to apply this transition when I remove the class, i think its easy i just can't think of anything atm. here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3JZsF/5/

sample html

```
<div id="img_gallery">
    <ul>
      <li>Testing List item</li>
      <li>Testing List item</li>
      <li>Testing List item</li>
      <li>Testing List item </li>
      <li>Testing List item</li>
      <li>Testing List item</li>
      <li>Testing List item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
(function(){

    var div = document.getElementById("img_gallery");
    div.onclick = function(){
        for(var i = 0; i < list.children.length; i++) {
            if(!list.children[i].className)
                list.children[i].className = "style";   
            else
                list.children[i].className = "";
        }
    }

})();
```

thank you

Comment: What transition? What effect has that `style` class?

Comment: @Bergi: It has a few properties that are being transitioned ... this works when clicking on the `li`'s but doesn't when I click again (by removing the class).

Comment: Then please include them in your post if they're relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying the `transition` property only to the dynamic class. Once the class is removed, there is no `transition` any more, and the fade will not be smooth. To fix this, simply put the `transition` outside of the dynamic selector, so that it is always applied to the elements in question:

```
li {
    transition: all 2s;
}
li.dynamic {
    …
}
```

([updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3JZsF/6/))